# How to wrap text in inline-block element?

Tags: html, css

Vertically centered the h4 element using inline-block, but unable to wrap  the text as the text goes out of parent div. Would like understand why it is  not auto wrapped. Tried word-wrap too but didn't work. I would like to have  the h4 element inside its parent.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent::before {
  white-space: pre;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="centerHelper"></span>
  <h4 class="centerElement">Overflowing text</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you expect to have ?

Comment: looks wrapped to me

Comment: When i use small text in h4 say "text" it stays within parent. If i use some large text say "overflow text elem" it goes out of the parent div. Need it inside parent only

Comment: Happens because of the height: 100% and the width of the text. Can be one or the other, or both.

Comment: Height:100%; because text needs to be aligned vertically.

Comment: @pjay Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `span` and `h4` are `inline-block`. So even a small space between them causing to overflow the content of `h4`.

> Using HTML comments as spacers between the elements works just as
>   placing no space between elements would:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.parent{  
  height:100px;  
  width:100px;  
  border:1px solid black;  
  margin-left:10px;  
}
span{  
  display:inline-block;  
  height:100%;  
  vertical-align:middle;  
}  
h4{  
  display:inline-block;  
  vertical-align:middle;  
  margin:0;  
  }  
.parent::before{  
  white-space:pre;  
  content:"";  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <span class="centerHelper"></span>
    <h4 class="centerElement">Overflowing text</h4>  
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<br> 
 <div class="parent">  
    <span class="centerHelper"></span><!--
    --><h4 class="centerElement">No Overflow with comment</h4>  
</div>
```

Comment: @pjay i don't agree with the use if comments like that, it's not intuitive and will make your code look very bad, there is a lot of better ways ... and for a better explanation, the small space is called a white space because inline-block element are treated like inline element ... in other words it's like space you add between words so `a text` is different from `atext`

Answer (score 0):

Why complicating with all this code when you can simply do this:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="centerElement">Overflowing text</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah its a nice idea. I was just curious about problem and wanted to have a better understanding on inline-block. Anyways thanks for this solution.

Comment: @pjay - Very wise. Useful as flexbox is, it's sound practice to have a good understanding of all the possible techniques, and how to choose between them for any particular situation.